# 'Stative / Dynamic'

Tags: grammar

In 'have a meeting', is 'have' stative or dynamic? The reason I ask is that in "Longman English Grammar" by L.G. Alexander, p. 201, I read that 'have' meaning 'possess' can be replaced by 'have got' and combines with appointments, etc.

And then I read an example "I have (got) an appointment with my dentist tomorrow." So my conclusion was - it is stative.

But in "Advanced Language Practice" by M.Vince, p.11, I came across:
"The team members are having a meeting tomorrow." and I felt confused.

My next question is about the verb 'own' which I always thought stative until I read: "More and more people are owning bicycles." (Advanced Language Practice, M.Vince, p.4.) Would you be so kind as to explain this to me?

Comment: I'm afraid you're having what we call an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). That is, you've asked the wrong question due to a false premise, meaning an assumption which is simply not true. So it's not possible to answer a question based on a false premise.

Comment: While 'He is owning a bicycle' is ungrammatical, 'More and more people are owning bicycles [etc] [nowadays]' is idiomatic, certainly acceptable, though it might be considered to stretch the boundaries of grammaticality. It might be seen as shorthand for 'More and more people are becoming bicycle owners [nowadays]'. Possibly this was unacceptable 80 years ago; English does keep on evolving.

Comment: *Having a meeting* is more active than *to have a meeting*. Having is like hosting a party or running a show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I**

"Have" is a verb that has both   stative and dynamic meanings, all well established; in this particular case of use with "meeting" "have" means "to do".

> (OALD) **16** ​ **have something** to perform a particular action
> ♦ I had a swim to cool down.
> ♦  (British English) to have a wash/shower/bath
> ♦ We had a very interesting discussion about climate change.

In the case of "appointment" it is more difficult to make out the verb. From [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/appointment?q=appointment) or [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/appointment) we see that an appointment is "*a formal arrangement to meet or visit somebody at a particular time*". There is however another meaning of the word appointment, and it can be inferred from the common phrases "[have an appointment tomorrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20an%20appointment%20tomorrow%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" and "[go to an appointment](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20to%20an%20appointment%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)"; it is evident that the arrangement is not situated tomorrow but that it exists before that time and that is is something quite abstract; similarly people do not "go to the arrangement", which is utter nonsense. It follows that "appointment" has one more signification (apparently not taken into account by some dictionaries); this is that signification that is proper for verbal expressions  such as "to go to", and "have" where "have" has a particular sense indicated by the continuous tense—"to have an arrangement"  in the sense of being in possession of directives (arrangement) is without problem, well defined. Then, if we devise  a supplementary sense of "appointment" as "the getting together with one or several persons at a place and time that have been decided through mutual arrangement". It follows that the verb "have" as, again, "to perform a particular action" will do and the continuous tense is without problem.

**II**

Certain explanations about this unusual usage of the continuous can be found in CoGEL § 4.28, p.200, and also in another source. (*: unacceptable; ?*: tending to unacceptability, but not fully unacceptable; ?: native speakers unsure about unacceptability)

> **Stative types A and B: qualities and states**
>
> Among stative situation types, a rough distinction may be drawn between
> QUALITIES […]  and STATES […]. Qualities are
> relatively permanent and inalienable properties of the subject referent. The
> primary verbs *be* and *have* are preeminently quality-introducing verbs; but
> they can also introduce the less permanent situation types called states.
> Contrast:
>
> |QUALITIES|STATES|
> |:-------|:---|
> |Mary is Canadian.     [1]|Mary is tired.      [3]|
> |Mary has blue eyes.      [2]|Mary has a bad cold.       [4]|
> Normally such stative situation types do not occur with the progressive (this
> is especially true of qualities):
>
> |QUALITIES|STATES|
> |:-------|:---|
> |*Mary is being a Canadian.     [1a]|?*Mary is being tired.      [3a]|
> |*Mary is having blue eyes.      [2a]|?Mary is having has a bad cold.       [4]|
> If sentences such as [1a-4a] do occur with the progressive, it is a sign that
> they have been in some sense reinterpreted as containing a dynamic predication. For example, *Peter is being awkward* signifies that 'awkwardness' is a form of behaviour or activity, not a permanent trait. If sentence [3a] were
> to occur, it would signify that Mary was *pretending* to be tired (*ie* indulging in
> a deceptive activity), rather than in a state of real lassitude.
> Although verbs with stative meaning have sometimes been called
> 'nonprogressive', we should observe that the definition of stative verbs is not so much that they are incompatible with the progressive, as that when they
> are combined with the progressive, some change of interpretation other than
> the addition of the 'temporary' meaning of the progressive aspect is required.
> This change of interpretation can usually be explained as a transfer, or
> reclassification of the verb as dynamic, *eg* as having a meaning of process or
> agentivity. The representative stative verbs *be*, *hope*, and *resemble*, are
> illustrated in *Table* 4.28:
>
> *Table* 4.28
>
> | **normal nonprogressive** | **nonnormal progressive** | **special effect of progressive** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | The neighbours *are* friendly. | The neighbours *are being* friendly. | Suggests that 'friendliness' is a form of behaviour (perhaps insincere). |
> | I *hope* you will come. | I *am hoping* you will come. | Makes the speaker's attitude more tentative and perhaps more polite […] |
> | Tina *resembles* her sister. | Tina *is resembling* her | With the comparative construction, the progressive turns the stative meaning into a process meaning[…]. |
>
> Another characteristic of such verbs, when they are expressing states, is that
> they can be used in a 'temporary' sense in the simple present tense:
>
> The manager *is* away this afternoon. [5]
>      The manager *works* this afternoon.  [6]
>
> For example, [5] is nonprogressive, and yet clearly refers to a limited period;
> in contrast, [6] cannot refer to a temporary state of affairs; instead, it has to
> be interpreted in a habitual sense ['The manager works this afternoon (being
> Tuesday) every week']. Equally, in [7]:
>
> The music they *are playing sounds* like Mahler. [7]
>
> the choice of the progressive with the dynamic verb *play* indicates the same
> limited time period as the use of the nonprogressive with the stative verb
> *sound*.
>
> <sub>Note
>
> The constraints of the progressive cannot, it seems, be explained entirely in terms of meaning.
> Since the use of the progressive aspect has been undergoing grammatical extension over the past
> few hundred years, it is likely that its use is still changing at the present day, and that its
> description at any one time cannot be totally systematic. This would explain the difficulties faced
> by those attempting to account in every respect for the conditions for the use of the progressive
> in terms of semantic generalizations.</sub>

Additionally, in *Practical English Usage*, second edition, p. 464, § 451 No 3, a note gives a general explanation, which is in keeping with user Edwin Ashworth's comment.

> Note also that many 'non-progressive' verbs are occasionally used in progressive forms in order to emphasize the idea of change or development.
>      *These days people **are preferring** to take early retirement.*
>      *The water **'s tasting** better today.*